# groupadd failure while writing changes to /etc/group

Tags: debian, permissions, group, android, selinux

I have been following [this](http://www.wdowiak.me/debian-kit/debian-kit_p04.html) guide on installing debian-kit on my Sony Xperia Tablet Z and the installation goes fine until I try to `apt-get install andromize` which fails with the error `groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group`. I also get the same message if I try to add a user with `adduser`.

I have partitioned my external SD card to 10gb FAT32 and 20GB ext2 and used the `mk-debian -i /dev/block/vold/179:37` which is the correct partition.

If I look in `/etc/` I can see that there are additional files called `group-` and `passwd-` as well as `group` and `passwd` but I have no idea if this is relevant.

I'm logged in as root and the partition is loaded readwrite because all other apt-get installs work, it just fails on any that modify the users / groups.

`ls -l /etc/group` returns the following...

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 476 Jul17 19:13 /etc/group
```

Comment: Doesn't the dot at the end of the attributes list from ls indicate that the file has an SELinux ACL associated with it? See [What does the dot mean at the end of -rw-r--r--.](http://superuser.com/questions/230559/what-does-the-dot-mean-at-the-end-of-rw-r-r-how-do-you-set-it-with-chmod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the end (inspired by @steeldriver) was to download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrbimc.selinux&hl=en_GB) app from the play store because under Android KitKat you need to change the SELinux mode to permissive.

A combination of that and `apt-get install selinux-policy-default` fixed the permission problems and LXDE now works great on my Sony Xperia Tablet Z

Answer (score 1):

or you do in android terminal:

```
...$ su
...# setenforce 0
```